# Bootstrap navbar dropdown button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve a dropdown menu using bootstrap in a `navbar`. I came across [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) and it obviously works perfectly. However I wanted to change the 1st dropdown ( from the left ) to a [dropdown button](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single). However if I try and change it to a button the styling gets all messed up ( see image below).

[image: navbar styling]

Relevant code:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo goes here</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select an Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Hollywood Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yet another Account</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

wrap the `.btn` in a wrapper classed as `navbar-form` to enable the padding as per the example given, like follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <!-- doesn't need to be a form element -->
        <form class="navbar-form">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select an Account<span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Hollywood Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Yet another Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- example using div and anchor instead of form and button -->
        <div class="navbar-form">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select an Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Hollywood Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Yet another Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here it is on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/reJdJo)

Comment: works perfectly. But why wrap in a form ? I wanted to give it a functionality like [this](http://www.bootply.com/b4NKREUPkN), that why I was trying to get `btn` work

Comment: the .navbar-form is what givs the button the correct padding as per the example, you're correct however, i don't need to be a `form` and the `.btn` doesn't need to be a `button` i used that in the example as that's what bootstrap use in their example, i have updated the codepen example to show both version form and div

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to have the btn wrapped in a form that makes no sense.  In bootstrap 3 you just need to add the class `.navbar-btn` to the button to have it vertically align in the navbar.  Also If you are only going to have the one button there is no reason to use a button group.  If you are going to have more than one button then use button group.  But the checked answer wrapping it in a form is just silly plus your adding another dom element for no reason. Try the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo goes here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select an Account<span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Hollywood Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yet another Account</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Drinkin People is correct

Simply changing this:

```
<a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select an Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

To this:

```
<a class="navbar-btn btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select an Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

It will center your button vertically in the navbar

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing the `<a>` tag into a `<button>` tag should do the trick.

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select an Account<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Hollywood Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Yet another Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: Checked on one of my own sites. Try removing the `<div class="btn-group">`.